# Шаг назад во время итерации

Tags: python

К примеру у меня есть код

```
l_iter = iter(l)
l_iter = iter(l)
for i in l_iter:
     if i == 1 and next(l_iter) == *любое значение*:
         *действие*
```

Так вот, уже при следующем `i` оно будет равно не 2, а 3 так как `next(l_iter)` перешло на следующий элемент. Можно как-то сделать шаг назад в итерации?

Comment: Нет. Можно только создать новый итератор и запустить по новой, остановить итератор, но нельзя откатываться назад.

Comment: Ну, запоминайте текущее значение итератора в какой-нибудь переменной. На следующей итерации эта переменная будет равна предыдущему шагу.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое

Comment: Значение итератора можно запомнить в другой переменной, но обе переменные будут разделять один и тот же итератор: `> i = iter([1, 2, 3]); j = i; next(i); next(j); next(i)` -> `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте оттолкнёмся от задачи: нужно перебрать последовательные пары из списка (или любой последовательности). К сожалению, в стандартной библиотеке такой функциональности нет. Справимся сами:

```
def pairs(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        prev = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    for item in it:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Тест:

```
> print(tuple(pairs([1, 2, 3, 4])))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Теперь ваша задача решается просто:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]
for i, j in pairs(l):
    if i == 1 and j == 2:
        print('found')
```